# Essential / popular TAXII feeds

Tags: siem, ioc

TAXII feeds are a great addition to a monitoring solution such as a SIEM. However, to my knowledge, there are only three distinct openly available providers:

- [Hail A TAXII](http://hailataxii.com/)
- [OTX](https://otx.alienvault.com/api)
- [Limo](https://www.anomali.com/community/limo)

What other threat feeds based on TAXII/STIX are available?

Comment: I'm not sure if such recommendations are on-topic, as available product and services change over time, though I don't know for sure

Comment: Requests for lists are off-topic as the list could be neverending. As well as "what product/service does X?"

Comment: TAXII is also just one way to share and get feeds. There is also MISP and STIX.